# Dynamic function call, depneding on condition in tensorflow graph

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to implement a `dynamic_rnn_decoder`. However, I get an exception, because after the second element the Tensors in the cell are already created. Thus I want to set `reuse=True` after the first iteration.
Is there a `op` which calls dynamically a function depending on a condition (like `fn_dyn = tf.cond(cond, fn1, fn2)`)

Hence, I want to implement this dynamically:

```
if i > 0:
    variable_scope.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
```

The a simplified `_time_step`-function for `_dynamic_rnn_loop` could be something like that:

```
def _time_step(time, output_ta_t, *state):
    input_t = input_ta.read(time)
    # Restore some shape information
    input_t.set_shape([const_batch_size, const_depth])

    # Pack state back up for use by cell
    state = (_packed_state(structure=state_size, state=state)
             if state_is_tuple else state[0])

    def call_with_previous(feed_previous_t):
        if feed_previous_t:
            prev = output_ta_t.read(time - 1)

            if output_projection is not None:
                prev = nn_ops.xw_plus_b(prev, output_projection[0], output_projection[1])

            cell_input = math_ops.reduce_max(prev, 1)
            print(cell_input.get_shape())

            cell_input.set_shape([const_batch_size, const_depth])
        else:
            cell_input = input_t

        def call_cell_t(cell_input_t, state_t):
            # set ruse after first call
            output_t, state_t = cell(cell_input_t, state_t)
            variable_scope.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()

            return output_t, state_t

        return lambda: call_cell_t(cell_input, state)

    # >>> doesn't work
    call_cell = tf.cond(tf.equal(time, tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32)),
                        call_with_previous(False),
                        call_with_previous(True))

    if sequence_length is not None:
        (output, new_state) = _rnn_step(
            time=time,
            sequence_length=sequence_length,
            min_sequence_length=min_sequence_length,
            max_sequence_length=max_sequence_length,
            zero_output=zero_output,
            state=state,
            call_cell=call_cell,
            state_size=state_size,
            skip_conditionals=True)
    else:
        (output, new_state) = call_cell()

    # Pack state if using state tuples
    new_state = (tuple(_unpacked_state(new_state)) if state_is_tuple else (new_state,))

    output_ta_t = output_ta_t.write(time, output)

    return (time + 1, output_ta_t) + new_state
```

Thanks, cheers!

Comment: I didn't entirely follow your question. Looking at your code, it seems that 'time' is a Python integer, not a Tensorflow tensor. So I think you can just use a Python 'if' statement; no need for a Tensorflow conditional. In general, if you know something at graph construction time (like time here), you can just use Python control flow constructs. Does this help?

Comment: Hi Peter! Thanks for your comment. time is a tensor (could be seen [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py#L768)). The snippet I posted, is the function, which should be executed as body in a tf.while_loop(..)-op and time is the index-variable.

Comment: If 'time' is a tensor, you can't have Python control flow (e.g., things like reuse_variables) depend on a Tensorflow value. Your computation needs to be separated into a first Python stage that builds the graph, and a second Tensorflow execution stage. The first stage cannot depend on the second, except by calling things like session.run(). However, is there a reason you can't simply set reuse_variables() unconditionally, even on the first iteration?

Comment: Briefly: I wanted to implement [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/seq2seq.py#L107) function with `while_loop`-ops, to handle outputs of variable length. So, the while-body should calculate the of step `time` with either the most probable output of `time-1` or the provided output of `time`. And, as far as I understood, the first input should be ignored (the GO-ID [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/seq2seq.py#L115)). However, as you recognized the `reuse_variable` isn't completely clear to me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while_loop only calls the underlying body function once.  not dynamically for every time step.  if you're getting an error when getting the variable, it's because you also access the variable elsewhere in your code.

In this case, looks like it's because of your cond statement.  this causes two calls to cell().  Try to factor this so the cell call is outside the cond.

Alternatively, as a hack, have the cell call inside a try except block. If you get a variable access error, just set reuse variable and call it again.

source: i wrote dynamic_rnn.

Comment: Hi eugene! Thanks alot for your answer and tips! I'll give it a try! (I know your name from the github commits :)